Question on a flapped vs non-flapped wings local lift coefficients
I'm developing a workflow in XFLR-5 for adding flaps/control surfaces to a wing design, and I encountered an interesting thing in my data results that I wanted some more insight on. In plotting a local lift coefficient graph, I noticed expectedly that the lift coefficient increased where the flaps are and had downward spikes at the ends of each flap, but interestingly all the non-flapped areas are still slightly higher overall.
In the picture, red is the ordinary wing, and blue is the same wing with a 10 degree flap hinged at 80% of chord length: 
It increases at the flapped area and shoots down at the ends of each flap like you'd expect, but why is the blue graph overall higher than the red despite the non-flapped area being the same angle of attack, airspeed, and airfoil shape? Is this an error in my simulations or is there a phenomenon/reason for this difference? If so, what is it?

The bound vorticity in the wing is substantially increased by the flap.  This is predominately felt in front of the flap, but it extends everywhere.
The bound vorticity is directly related to the circulation of the sections.  It causes downwash at the trailing edge and upwash at the leading edge.
The upwash on the outboard parts of the wing causes an effective increase in angle of attack and pushes them to higher lift coefficient.
